# Read a sas7bdat file in SAS Studio

Tags: sas

I've scoured the internet but cannot seem to figure this out. My question is, if I have a sas7bdat file, how can I read a sas7bdat file in SAS studio so that I can work with it.

I've tried:

```
libname test 'C:\Users\name\Downloads\test.sas7bdat';
```

which gives me the error that library test does not exist and if I try the following, I know that I need an INPUT which I don't know of unless I can see into the file.

```
DATA test; 
    INFILE 'C:\Users\lees162\Downloads\test.sas7bdat'; 
RUN;
```

Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: Here's video tutorial on how to do this, that covers most scenarios. https://video.sas.com/detail/video/4005088074001/accessing-your-existing-data:-for-sas-university-edition?autoStart=true&page=1&q=your%20data

Comment: In addition, a relatively foul proof method is to go to the Servers Folders & Files Pane in SAS Studio on the left hand side. Navigate to the file you want to use. Right click it and select properties. The path and file name there is what you want to use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Libname is just pointing the location and once you have done that you can use that libname followed period and dataset in your set statement

```
  libname test "C:\Users\name\Downloads"; 

 DATA test; 
 set  test.asl; 
 RUN;
```

Comment: Thanks Kiran. So I actually used asl in one of the samples but I wanted to use test. In this case, how would you indicate the test file under downloads under the data step?

Comment: then it would be test.test

Comment: so I tried test.test and got the error File TEST.TEST.DATA does not exist. Did I do something wrong? Or can there not be more than one file in my Downloads folder?

Comment: did u try in set statement

Comment: Yes, I put: DATA test; 
 set  test.test; 
 RUN;

Comment: to your left do you see test library

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183145/discussion-between-kiran-and-serena-lee).

Comment: You can use the same word for the libref, dataset name, a variable name, etc. But it might cause you to get confused.  If SAS says the data is not there it is not there. But remember that if you ask for `test.test` then SAS is looking for a file name in all lowercase letters. So `test.sas7bdat` in the directory that `test` points to.  Not `Test.sas7bdat` or `test.SAS7BDAT`.

Answer (score 5):

Libref's that you create via the `LIBNAME` statement point to directories, not individual files.

```
libname test 'C:\Users\name\Downloads\';
```

`INFILE` is for reading raw data files. To reference an existing SAS dataset you use a `SET` statement (or `MERGE`,`MODIFY`,`UPDATE` statement).

```
set test.test ;
```

Note that you can skip defining a libref and just use the quoted physical name in the SET statement.

```
DATA test; 
  set 'C:\Users\lees162\Downloads\test.sas7bdat'; 
RUN;
```

Of course to use `C:\` in the paths this is assuming that you are using SAS/Studio to point to full SAS running on your PC.  If you are using SAS University Edition then it is running in a virtual machine and you will need to put the SAS dataset into a folder that is mapped to the virtual machine and then reference it in the SAS code with the name that the virtual machine uses for the directory.

So something like:

```
DATA test; 
  set '/folders/myfolders/test.sas7bdat'; 
RUN;
```

Answer (score 1):

One possible reason could be that you are using the SAS University edition (It doesn't support variable library address).

**From one of the SAS community Q/A:**

"*When you are using the SAS University Edition, any libraries that you create must be assigned to a shared folder. You access your shared folder with this pathname: /folders/myfolders/. Always use '/' in the directory path, even in Windows operating environments*"

After setting the directory address, proceed as instructed by Tom above in one of the answers.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you have the sas dataset at location. C:\Users\name\Downloads\test.sas7bdat

```
libname download 'C:\Users\name\Downloads'; 

proc sql;

select * from downloads.test;

run;
```

you can read your dataset like a table using the proc sql, in case you want to query the dataset, but if you want to modify the existing dataset then you can use the data setp as mentioned by @krian.

Comment: Not really an answer to this question.  Plus it is not valid SAS syntax because the name used as the libref cannot be more than 8 characters long.  DOWNLOADS is 9 characters.

Comment: @Tom : don't know that exactly you mean by not really an answer to this question. the questions is taking about reading the sas dataset. and i think sql is better way to query the data then using the data setp. and thanks for pointing to libref name, i have corrected that and changed to 8 character.